# containsKey check for hashmap

Tags: java

I have read multiple posts to understand this, but I can't seem to quite get in on why we do a check if a map does not contain a key before performing a put operation? For eg,

```
    if(!myMap.containsKey(myKey) {
    myMap.put(myKey,myValue);
}
```

Why do we need this check? Either way, map doesn't allow duplicate key, and replaces the key with the new value if the key already exists. So why do we need to check this explicitly? Is this check needed for all implementations of Map? I am sorry if this is a very basic question. I can't seem to find an answer to this exact question. If there are posts that answer this that I may have missed, please point me to them, and feel free to mark mine as duplicate.

Comment: it depends on use case, you check if you want to see if the item is already mapped, there is no specific answer to this unclear question

Comment: Obviously, sometimes you do not want to *replace* already existing (key,value) pair.

Comment: What if you don't want your previous value to be replaced? You would lose some important data in case you replace the value in the map for a particular key.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct. In fact the above check sounds like a bug waiting to happen to me. "Why are my values not updating".

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - I don't see how my post is unclear to you. R.J. - Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: by unclear I mean, there is not exact question that can be answered absolutely here, this is totally usecase dependent question, for example if you want to count character occurance on word and you have mapped character to occurances while traversing through character you would like to read and increment in that case you see if it contains key

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - With all due respect, I don't think you originally meant that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check because sometimes you don't want to update the map's value if the key is already present. I think this is a widely used block of code where the map is mutable/ modifiable but prevents overwriting of values.

Answer (score 0):

Map `value` is also overwritten when `key` is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to add reference to those multiple posts here to see detailed description.

Maps indeed do not allow "multiple" entries, so when you call `put(key, value)` you actually replace the existing value or create new entry. So, if you are interesting in the last set entry only you can call `put()` without any check. If however you are interesting in first entry only you should check existence of the key before put.

The example is difference between properties file and Windows ini fie. If you have 2 entries with the same key in properties the last value will be set. However when parsing ini file the first duplicate entry will be taken.